# existence of a finite group which is the union of self normalizing subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

Can a finite group G be the union of self normalizing subgroups such that the intersection between  any two of these subgroups is equal to the unit of the group G? I don't think so but I can't prove it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12):

The anwer is **No**.

Let $H_1,\dots, H_n$ be a family of subgroups of $G$ whose union equals $G$ and whose pairwise intersection is trivial. In the literature we call such a family a **partition of $G$ by subgroups**.

The partitions of all finite groups are explicitly known - in the solvable case thanks to Baer, and in the general case by Suzuki. The possibilities for partitions are listed at Example 3.5.1 in Schmidt's book [*Subgroup lattices of groups*](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=EuVadOnix5MC&printsec=frontcover). (Email me if you want an e-copy of this book.)

You can go through the list of families and see, explicitly, that each partition contains a subgroup that is non-self-normalizing. In particular the four main examples are when $G$ is a Frobenius group, or when $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$, $\mathrm{PSL}_2(q)$ or $\mathrm{Sz}(q)$; there is one more family which is built using one of these four families - since these four families are partitioned using non-self-normalizing subgroups, he last family will be also.

Note that this result on partitions doesn't use the Classification of Finite Simple Groups. It still uses some heavy-duty maths though, so one might still hope to find a more direct argument - the presence of the Suzuki groups in the classification suggests to me that such an argument would need to deal with the case when $G$ is simple, and then move to the general situation.

Answer (score 7):

To expand a little on Nick Gill's answer: it was a common theme in some early classification-type theorems that a simple group might be a disjoint union of Hall subgroups with trivial intersection of any two of them. This occurs for example, in Suzuki's classification of simple CA-groups ( groups in which all non-identity elements have Abelian centralizers)- I do not know whether Suzuki was thinking about groups with a partition before he did that classification. The Suzuki groups are simple CN-groups ( nonidentity elements have nilpotent centralizers)-there are simple CN-groups with no such partition, eg ${\rm PSL}(2,7), {\rm PSL}(2,9), {\rm PSL}(2,17)$ - in these last groups, Sylow $2$-subgroups can have non-trivial intersections. Quite often, delicate character theory was needed in these classifications. Also, by Frobenius's theorem, if $G$ is a finite simple group, and $M$ is a nilpotent Hall subgroup of $G$ disojoint from its other conjugates, then $M$ can't be self normalizing (there are finite simple groups which have a Sylow $2$-subgroup which is a maximal subgroup, eg ${\rm PSL}(2,17)$). Hence it follows for general reasons(without CFSG but as Nick says, with some quite difficult group theory) that in a finite non-Abelian simple group which admits a partition by nilpotent Hall subgroups, these can't all be self-normalizing and disjoint from their other conjugates ( apart from the identity). However, at the moment I don't see how to tackle directly ( ie without CFSG, and with easier results than Nick quotes ) partitions of the type asked about here (even just for simple groups).

Later edit: In a completely different direction, (though this may be covered by Baer's work, which predates Carter subgroups), a finite solvable group $G$ is never a union of proper nilpotent self-normalizing subgroups : for $G$ has a unique conjugacy class of nilpotent self-normalizing subgroups, the Carter subgroups, and no finite group is the union of a single conjugacy class of proper subgroups (if $G$ itself is nilpotent, it has no proper self-normalizing subgroups at all).

Comment: That's a cool fact about Carter subgroups. I didn't know about those.